What are these strange katakana words in the lyrics of "*Hello, Planet"?
The only translation I could find for the lyrics of sasakure.UK's hit Vocaloid song (link to an official video on the producer's channel, but the song is much older than this) doesn't seem very accurate - there's a lot that I would have rendered differently, and some of it isn't even proper English. But one verse in particular is troublesome - the translator seems to have completely punted on some katakana, and I'm almost as lost:

つなぐつながる　ユメとメトロジカ
まわるまわるよ　ミチのエントロピカ
イエスか　ノーか　フシギのコトバニカ
マエか　ウシロか　すすめテクノポリカ

My question is about the parts in boldface. My guess is that the カs here are particle-ka (despite being written in katakana - there is no mistake about the choice, since the lyrics are transcribed from the video). That would allow:

テクノポリ -> "technopolis"? (Some sort of portmanteau of "technology" and "metropolis")
コトバニ -> I guess this is just 言葉に
エントロピ -> entropy
メトロジ -> Here I'm at a complete loss. I only know メトロ as either "metro" (i.e. subway) or as short for メトロノム. I can't find any way to make the ジ make sense.

The entire song uses fanciful imagery, so unusual nouns aren't unexpected here; but I really can't figure out this verse. (There's also a question raised in comments on the fan translator's subtitle video about whether this ミチ is 道 or 未知 - I could make a bit of sense out of either, but it still seems like a strange metaphorical phrase.)

Seeing the combination of "metro" and "techno(poli)" reminded me of Technopolis, a classic of Japanese techno music. カ at the end is definitely not a question particle.

On a side note, would 不思議な言葉 be more correct than の?

I think there exist a strong influence from Latin suffix -ica or its descendants to make sound rhyming and exotic as well as their katakana spelling. (I personally recall the Encyclopedia Britannica, by the way.)
As they are words coined by the composer possibly intended not to be understood easily, I cannot say anything for sure. But メトロジカ and テクノポリカ seems mix up of metro-polis and techno-logy, even though they are used apart. Or perhaps related to another word with -logy like metrology, meteorology, mythology, methodology...?
